# why is my pl/sql code displays output twice?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables employee and employees

employee

```
 EMPID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME       SALARY DEPARTMENT CREDENTIALS
```

---

```
     1 ANITHA     SHARMA          30000 ASSURANCE
     2 EZIO       AUDITORE        50000 ASSURANCE
     3 CONNOR     KENWAY          20000 SUPPORT
     4 SAMANTHA   JO              25000 ASSURANCE
     5 EDWARD     MILES           52000 ITIS
```

employees

```
EMP_ID EMP_NAME                EMP_AGE EMP_SALARY     BATHCH
```

---

```
     1 charan                       20      30000
     0                               0          0
     1 goku                         32       1223
     2 gokul                        24     100000
```

when i tried to write a pl/sql code to print emp_name,firstname,salary from the above two tables, it prints the records twice.The pl/sql code is

```
    declare
cursor c1 is select * from employee,employees where employee.salary=employees.emp_salary;
c2 c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into c2;
dbms_output.put_line(c2.firstname||' '||c2.emp_name||' '||c2.salary);
exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;
end;
/
```

I am getting the output as

```
ANITHA charan 30000
ANITHA charan 30000
```

Comment: Your loop exit condition is after your print statement. Switch the statements and only one line is printed. The reasoning if left as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: @user272735 Thanks, It worked.Could you explain why it is printed twice more clearly.

Comment: when a print statement is inside the loop, it will print one more time then desired. If the result of query is in 1 statement, the iteration will try to execute second time, if fails then it exits. But in your condition before it exits it prints the result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @NiravMadariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `exit when` clause after `fetch`. In your case, the `dbms_output.put_line` is getting executed twice. For the second iteration, `c2` would still hold previous values even when `not found` condition is true.

You should always use `exit when` after `fetch` unless you have a requirement not to do so.

```
declare
cursor c1 is select * from employee,employees where employee.salary=employees.emp_salary;
c2 c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into c2; 
exit when c1%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(c2.firstname||' '||c2.emp_name||' '||c2.salary);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this,

```
    declare
cursor c1 is select * from employee,employees where employee.salary=employees.emp_salary;
c2 c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into c2;
dbms_output.put_line(c2.firstname||' '||c2.emp_name||' '||c2.salary);
exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Use this,

```
    declare
cursor c1 is select * from employee,employees where employee.salary=employees.emp_salary;
c2 c1%rowtype;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into c2; 
exit when c1%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(c2.firstname||' '||c2.emp_name||' '||c2.salary);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: It didn't work ,still I am getting the output twice.

Comment: @RagavCharan Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NiravMadariya